# hydrateRoot forces to pass same context even though it has already been rendered by the server

Tags: reactjs

If the component is rendered on the server side with `renderToString(<App model={data} />)`, then it looks as if same `data` has to be used when component is hydrated on the client side `hydrateRoot(root, <App model={data}>)`, otherwise it throws the error - *UI doesn't match...*

I haven't found any option other than just simply output the data in `<script type="application/json" id="r-data">JSON.stringify(data)</script>` along with each component so that it can be taken and passed back to App on the client side when hydrated:

```
 const componentRoot = document.querySelector('.r-root');
 const data = document.getElementById('r-data'); // <script type="application/json" id="r-root">
 
 const root = hydrateRoot(componentRoot, <List model={JSON.parse(data.textContent)}/>)
```

Which works!

But, falsely I assumed it would make sense if, no matter what you pass while hydrating the component, it won't change initial output rendered on the server, so that I can call `root.render(<List model={newModel}/>` later on each time the model is dynamically changed upon user action, but apparently `const root = hydrateRoot(root, <List />)` on the page load doesn't work

I'm new to react and working on the legacy project with the idea to infest it gradually with the stand along react components, but keep core functionality as is.

So I'm looking for the better way to pass data between back and front, keeping in mind that it is mandatory to have key content rendered on the server side on the first page load